# Find the most popular 5 words with bash command

Tags: bash, macos

I need to find the 5 most popular words in a random text, with a bash command. I was trying to make different combinations between `cat`, `wc`, `uniq`, `sort` and `tail`, but couldn't get to anything. Either my output would be a single word, or the text itself, or the wordcount of the text... I should be missing smth...

Is it even possible with a one-liner? Should I approach the problem with smth "a level up", like `for-do`?

F.e. as input: [this random text](http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html) (I've got other texts for my data, but they're too large to show here), and output... well, the 5 most used words (I don't know which ones they are currently :D ).

Comment: Add an example content and your desired output from that.

Comment: sed 's/ /\n/g' test.txt | awk 'max<++c[$0] {max=c[$0]} END {for(i in c)printf "%s %s\n",c[i],i}'
| sort -r  | head -5  This will work on a file with spaces. Replace everything by new line and count uniq lines. I found part of it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat lorem.txt | tr \  '\n' | tr -c -d '[:alpha:]\n' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -5
     10 vitae
     10 in
      9 quis
      9 nunc
      9 eget
```

Walk-thru:

- `tr \  '\n'` separate words on separate records
- `tr -c -d '[:alpha:]\n'` remove non-letters
- `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` convert to lower case
- `sort | uniq -c |sort -nr` sort, count and print in frequency order
  |head -5 exit in five

Comment: @lmo Yeah, I kind of left it uncommented because it was a rewrite of my annotated awk solution--plus I fell asleep. I quess awk version is less boring, eh?

Comment: Does `\ ` after the first `tr` signify a whitespace (space)?

Comment: @Milkncookiez A bit (lot) late but yes.

Answer (score 3):

Does awk count?

```
BEGIN {
    RS=FS                                  # separate words on separate records
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"  # set sort order to pick most frequent
} 
{
    gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"")                   # remove non-letters
    a[tolower($0)]++                       # convert to lower case and count words
} 
END {
    for(i in a) {                          # go thru array in frequency order
        print i,a[i]                       # print
        if(++j==5); exit                   # exit in five
    }
}
$ awk -f this.awk lorem.txt
vitae 10
in 10
quis 9
eget 9
nunc 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat words | perl -pe 's/[\W+]/\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr  | head -n6
111
 10 vel
  8 ut
  8 turpis
  8 sit
  8 erat
```

sort -n6 because it prints whitespace as top-1 entry

Answer (score 1):

This script makes `vitae` and `vitae?` equal. Perhaps you also want eveything in lowercase?
I think that the `awk` solution of @Brown is better, but a solution with your commands would look like

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]/ /g' loremIpsum.txt |
   tr ' ' '\n' | grep . |  sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5

      8 non
      7 vitae
      7 vestibulum
      7 vel
      7 purus
```